# Permanent indexes in RavenDB

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I currently want to create some static indexes for RavenDB to gain better performance.

But when I was going through RavenDB [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes?version=1) there was one specific sentence which really made me reconsider my original intentions.

> Therefore, we recommend to base most operations in an application on static indexes, **or at least ensure the temporary indexes created by dynamic indexing have been promoted to permanent indexes.**

Well since my solution is really large and I don't even know which indexes I need. It would force me to look through whole solution and create static indexes for every other operation. I probably exaggerating, but still... I don't know if all that work will be worth it.

My question is:

How to ensure the temporary indexes have been promoted to permanent indexes?

**EDIT:**

What I learned is the fact that some indexes gets promoted to permanent/static auto indexes which are persisted and I don't lose them even if I restart Raven server. What I understood is that it depends on Server `Configuration options`. So some  of my indexes have been promoted to permanent and with restart I have lost only those temporary. Nevertheless my question remains.

**EDIT2:**

I made edits in original question and gathered more information. Take me as really stupid person. I need explanations. Please do not confuse me with things like `"permanent/static"`

Static index is permanent, but Permanent index is not necessarily `static`. Maybe I am asking wrong question. I just want to be sure RavenDb server don't have to create new Dynamic index each call of query which I don't really call one hundred times per minute.

> RavenDB can analyse a query and create a temporary index on the fly, which will be persisted for some amount of time before then being disposed of.

What I understood from Ravendb server configuration options:

Index gets promoted to Permanent when you use it one hundred times in one minute(default values). And if it remains dynamic and it's not used for 20 minutes it's deleted.(default).
But what if I have queries which will be used I don't know
**TempIndexPromotionMinimumQueryCount / 2** per **TempIndexPromotionThreshold**. So maybe my question is now:

*Is there any significant difference between constantly used but dynamic index and permanent index?*

Comment: Have any of the replies answered your question. If not, can you provide additional information? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What that statement means is that if a dynamic/temporary index is being used a lot by your application, its better to convert it into a static/permanent index.

Comment: What you mean by "Convert it into static index"? If you mean I have to/should create corresponding static index then You are wrong it's not what it really means. Server itself promotes some indexes to be permanent.

Comment: Yes RavenDB will promote frequently used dynamic indexes to permanent/static indexes. A good design strategy is to have static indexes for indexes which use predicates.

Comment: Well thank you, but I still want to know the answer which will cover my question.

Comment: Promoting an index IS converting it into a static index.

Comment: @AyendeRahien I am confused right now, who was your comment intended for? Btw in RavenDB documentation it says `manually created indexes are called static indexes.`

Comment: Viktor - "permanent" is synonym for "static" and "temporary" is synonym for "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic index (constantly used or not):

1. Is *always* created by RavenDB because cannot use an existing dynamic/static index to answer your query
2. Only exists in memory, not on disk.
3. Will **not** be there if the Raven Server is restarted
4. Will be deleted if the usage does not pass a certain threshold of queries/time elapsed
5. Has a lower priority on resources for maintenance over static indexes

In contrast to static indexes. A static index:

1. Is either

   - a manually/automatically promoted dynamic index
   - a static index defined manually in Raven Studio
   - Created in .NET code by an application and registered with RavenDB
2. Is stored on disk
3. Will be reloaded if Raven Server restarts
4. Will never be deleted by Raven Server automatically
5. Is given a higher priority to maintain.

Yes dynamic indexes do have a priority too, but static indexes are first priority in maintenance, followed by dynamic.

You also stated that your application is very 'large' (high volume/high variety/high throughput?), and I assume that there must have been some development cycle on a developer machine. Through developer testing, you may already have indexes created for you. The next steps are how to move them across to production.

You have 3 choices in this:

1. Let RavenDB work it out itself (dynamic -> static)
2. Copy/paste the definitions from environment to environment. (static)
3. [RECOMMENDED] Create the index in code. (static)

A recommended approach, is if you know ahead of time what you are indexing, it is best to create a class that implements `AbstractIndexCreationTask<T>` and then register it. The documentation for [creating a static index in code](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/static-indexes/defining-static-index) is found on the RavenDB website.
This way you will also have a consistent set of indexes across your environments.